# Show that $ f(x,y) =y^{-1}(\sqrt{1+xy}-1)$ if $y \neq 0$, $f(x,0)=x/2$, defines $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show that:
$$
 f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{1+xy}-1 }{y}  & y \neq 0\\x/2 & y= 0\end{cases} 
$$
is differentiable in $(0,0)$

I don't know where exactly is my mistake. I try to do it by calculating partial derivatives in (0,0) and then I have relevant linear transformation $A(x,y)=1/2x$(one place where I could've gone wrong) and then check if $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}  \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-A(x,y)}{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} }  \rightarrow 0$. But it doesn't (second place where I could've gone wrong).

Comment: Why do you think it doesnt? Seems ok to me.

Comment: It seems like both partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: You went wrong in "the second place" only and you could try to make your approach work by showing that $$\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\frac12x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=-\frac{x^2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(1+\sqrt{1+xy})^2}$$ whose limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ should be clear. A useful algebraic tool to show this is the identity $$\sqrt{1+u}-1=\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u}+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, by Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$, one has
$$
\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac{u}2+O(u^2),
$$ giving, as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+xy}-1 }{y}=\frac{1+\frac{xy}2+O(x^2y^2)-1 }{y}=\frac{x}2+O(x^2y).
$$